# Why is my lock file of netbeans not deleting*

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

My netbeans 8.2 is not working.On searching about it ,I got that i need to delete the lock file.I deleted it but whenever i reopen it,the lock file is generated again and netbeans don't start.

Comment: What's exactly the problem, what errors you're seeing?

Comment: Due to some fluctuation,my pc shut down and netbeans didn't close properly and a lock file was created.We i tried to open it later after deleting lock file,netbeans loads and lock file is generated again,causing it not to open...

It gives a warning that an instance exist in c:/**/users/**/app data/roaming/netbeans